# Calculating averages of hierarchical data in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, parent-child, average, dax, hierarchical-data

Currently we are working on designing a dashboard in PowerBI to show benchmark statistics.

We have data from over 200 companies from the last 3 years. This data is retrieved from a questionnaire. Over the years we developed this questionnaire and put more detail into it.

The data is hierarchal (on 5 levels) and contains information on the full time equivalent. The levels go from 1 (the most general) to level 5 (the most detailed). For example, the category in level 1 is 411 in the example, but can be broken down in multiple, more detailed levels (411 --> 4111 --> 41112 --> 411123 --> 4111231).

```
ID     Level1     Level2    Level3    Level4    Level5   Absolute value   Relative value
1      411        4111      41112     411123    4111231  2                 20%
1      411        4111      41112     411123    4111232  3                 30%
2      411        4111      41112     411123             4                 40%
```

As you see in the example, ID_2 didn't report the data on the lowest level, but ID 1 did. This is how the data was retrieved over time. We don't know how the value of 411123 for ID 2 is divided over 4111231 and 4111232.

The goal is to make an average of the relative value.

Our problem:

If we calculate the averages it goes wrong when on the parent row, more organizations are included in the averages, where in the child row less organizations are included. This goes wrong in a matrix table (see below).

```
Category       Average of the relative value
411123         45% (Both ID 1 and ID 2 included)
   4111231     20% (Only ID 1 included)
   4111232     30% (Only ID 1 included)
```

The 20% and 30% do not match with the 45% on the main level (411123).
How do we want to solve this: we would like to use the ratio of ID 1 (so, 20%/50% for 411231 and 30%/50% for 4111232) and apply it to ID 2 (the 40%).

Can you help us?

If you have any questions, please let us know.

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards,

Floris

Comment: Can you post the measures you've come up with so far?